# QSplitter when trying to grab drag handle end up getting the ui elements underneath it (mac)

Tags: qsplitter

QSplitter is used in my application , while dragging splitter handle i end up dragging the elements underneath it. [image]

In this picture when I try to drag the splitter handle ( highlighted by red rect) I end up dragging green line which is actually underneath/behind it.

Request you to throw some light on this issue